# (android) Implementing application lockscreen?

Tags: android, launcher, lockscreen

I was looking into the best possible route to create a lockscreen for my application...

I thought it would be as easy as calling my lockscreen from an onStop() callback, but unfortunately my lockscreen "locks" whenever I enter a different activity.

I need to know, when the user loads the launcher activity... then - "BAM!" apply my lockcreen ...

Any idea guys?

OR! I could derive from Activity - and call unlock() automatically which stops the application from locking itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could, Nathan - on each onStart() event, call unlock on your lockscreen. This way, when you exit out of YOUR application, nothing will call doUnlock() and stop your lock screen!

(I always think of the answers when I post the question!)